# filter and limit dataframe rows at the same time

Tags: r

How can I apply a filter to my dataframe AND also select only the top 100 rows?

With two operations, I can do this:

```
 df1 = df[ 1:100, ]
 df2 =  [ grep('requiredvalue', df1$var) ]
```

**Question:** How can I do this in one operation, e.g. something like:

```
 df1 = df[ 1:100, grep('somevalue', df$var) ]
```

Comment: Don't you need an additional comma in `df2 =  [ grep("requiredvalue", df1$var) ]` or am I misunderstanding your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df1, (row_number() %in% 1:100) & grepl('somevalue', var))
```

Using the example

```
filter(df1, (row_number() %in% 1:20) & grepl('A', var))
#   var       val
#1   A -4.469564
#2   A  0.369045
#3   A -1.822190
```

Or using `base R`

```
 df1[1:nrow(df1)%in% 1:20  & grepl('A', df1$var),]
 #   var       val
 #17   A -4.469564
 #18   A  0.369045
 #20   A -1.822190
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(var=sample(LETTERS[1:5], 40, replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(40))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df[1:100, ][grep('somevalue', df$var[1:100]), ]
```

or:

```
subset(df[1:100, ], grepl('somevalue', var))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also:

Create dummy data,

```
df = data.frame(v1=c("a", "b", "c"), v2=rnorm(3000))
```

Select only those rows with b in the first column.

```
head(df[df$v1=="b",], 100)
```